KivyMd - No aparecen ningún botón
Estoy intentando hacer un juego simple del ahorcado para practicar con kivyMD, pero desde el vamos estoy teniendo problemas. Al anotar el típico código inicial, nada figura en la pantalla. El archivo .py es:
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import MDScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen


class AhorcadoScreen(MDScreen):
    pass


class MainScreen(MDScreen):
    pass


class WindowManager(MDScreenManager):
    pass


class JuegodePalabrasApp(MDApp):
    
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("juegodepalabras.kv")
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    JuegodePalabrasApp().run()

y probé con 3 distintos archivos de kivy. El primero es:
WindowManager:
    MainScreen:
    AhorcadoScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: "mainscreen"

    
    MDScrollView:
        md_bg_color: "white"

        MDButton:
            style: "elevated"

El segundo es:
WindowManager:
    MainScreen:
    AhorcadoScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: "mainscreen"
    

    MDScreen:
        MDScrollView:
            md_bg_color: "white"

            MDButton:
                style: "elevated"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}

                MDButtonText:
                    text: "Ahorcado"

Y el último:
WindowManager:
    MainScreen:
    AhorcadoScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: "mainscreen"

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        md_bg_color: "white"

        MDScreen:
            MDScrollView:
                md_bg_color: "white"

                MDButton:
                    style: "elevated"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}

                    MDButtonText:
                        text: "Ahorcado"

Pero en todos los casos, lo único qu obtengo es una pantalla en blanco. Es el mismo código que usé en otros programas, pero en este caso no parece funcionar.
Estoy usando el mismo venv que en los otros programas, por si eso tiene algo que ver.
Alguna idea de lo que sucede?

Lo que parece estar pasando es que el color de "fondo" está aplicandose encima de todo, lo puedes ver claramente si estableces un fondo con transparencia:
<MainScreen>:
    name: "mainscreen"
    
    MDScrollView:
        md_bg_color: 1, 1, 1, 0.5

        MDButton:
            style: "elevated"
            
            MDButtonText:
                text: "Ahorcado"


Si estableces el fondo en la instancia de MDScreen:
<MainScreen>:
    name: "mainscreen"
    md_bg_color: "white"
    
    MDScrollView:
        MDButton:
            style: "elevated"
            MDButtonText:
                text: "Ahorcado"

Funciona correctamente (ver aclaración más abajo):

Otra opción es usar un widget que actue de padre del ScrollView (como un layout) y establecer el fondo en él, dejando el del scroll view transparente.
<MainScreen>:
    name: "mainscreen"
    
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        md_bg_color: "white"

        MDScrollView:
            MDButton:
                style: "elevated"

                MDButtonText:
                    text: "Ahorcado"


Independientemente de esto, ciertas inconsistencias me hacen pensar que hay algunos bugs relativos a la aplicación de la propiedad md_bg_color en kv language en KivyMD (2.0.1). Por ejemplo:
main.py
from kivymd.app import MDApp


class JuegodePalabrasApp(MDApp):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    JuegodePalabrasApp().run()

juegodepalabras.kv
WindowManager:
    MainScreen:
    AhorcadoScreen:
            
<MainScreen@MDScreen>
    name: "mainscreen"
    md_bg_color: "white"

    MDScrollView:
        MDButton:
            style: "elevated"
            MDButtonText:
                text: "Ahorcado"        

                   
<WindowManager@ScreenManager>
<AhorcadoScreen@MDScreen>

Muestra exactamente le mismo problema, pero si importamos la clase en Python:
main.py
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen


class JuegodePalabrasApp(MDApp):
   pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    JuegodePalabrasApp().run()

con el mismo.kv todo fucniona perfectamente.
Si aplicamos el fondo como hariamos en kivy "crudo", modificando el canvas del widget, tambien funciona como debe:
juegodepalabras.kv
WindowManager:
    MainScreen:
    AhorcadoScreen:

            
<MainScreen@MDScreen>
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

    name: "mainscreen"
    MDScrollView:
        MDButton:
            style: "elevated"
            MDButtonText:
                text: "Ahorcado"   

                   
<WindowManager@ScreenManager>
<AhorcadoScreen@MDScreen>

o en el mismo ScrollView:
juegodepalabras.kv
WindowManager:
    MainScreen:
    AhorcadoScreen:

            
<MainScreen@MDScreen>
    name: "mainscreen"
    MDScrollView:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        MDButton:
            style: "elevated"
            MDButtonText:
                text: "Ahorcado"   

                   
<WindowManager@ScreenManager>
<AhorcadoScreen@MDScreen>

Es como si estubira aplicando el fondo en el orden incorrecto al generar cada frame, como si se usara canvas.after en vez de canvas.before.

Una observación, si llamas a tu .kv igual que a tu  clase principal (deriva de MDApp), se cargará automáticamente. Si además lo cargas explícitamente usando Builder.load_file, estarás cargando el archivo dos veces, lo cual puede desencadenar errores (de hecho genera un warning).

Buenísimo. Ahí se arregló. Muchas gracias. Con respecto al nombre del archivo .kv, lo sabía, pero primero tenía otro nombre la clase principal. Pero después lo cambié y me olvidé de modificarlo.
